# Why aren't my assets rendering in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I've been working on a Rails [app to conglomerate directories pulled from IPFS](https://github.com/dhappy/tip). For some reason, `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` [isn't rendering](http://tip.dhappy.org).

Each IPFS entry has a corresoponding ActiveRecord model. The relevant parts of `routes.rb` are:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :entries, path: :e, constraints: { id: /.*/ }
  root 'entries#index'
end
```

The `index` action of `EntriesController` is:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @entries = @space.roots
  end
end
```

My `application.html.erb` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tip</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <% if notice %>
    <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
  <% end %>
  <% if alert %>
    <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your code, ran it locally, debugged and made a few tests.

Turns out that the blame is on the initialize of the controller, if you change it to this, it works:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController

  # def initialize(*args)
  #   @space = Space.first_or_create()
  # end

  def index
    @entries = Space.first_or_create().roots
  end

  def show
    id =  params[:id]

    if id.start_with?('.../')
      @entry = @space.lookup(id)
    else
      @hash = id
      @entry = Entry.find_or_create_by(code: @hash)

      if @entry.parents.empty? && !@space.roots.include?(@entry)
        @space.roots << @entry
      end
    end

    if @entry.kind_of?(Blob)
      send_data @entry.content, type: 'text/html', disposition: 'inline'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I needed to call the super class constructor. Thanks for helping me find it. I was befuddled.